# Loop assignment error matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, variable-assignment

Today isn't my day with MATLAB guys...

I was trying to do the simplest of things get into a structure pull a value and assign it to an object incrementally. Turns out I'm getting the infuriating `In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.` error.

Here's what I have:

```
 for e=1:length(EEG.event)
  Type(e)=EEG.event(e).type
 end
```

I tried this too:

```
for e=1:length(EEG.event)
  Type(e)=EEG.event(1,e).type
end
```

But still no success. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why are you doing this kind of assignment using a loop? This is quite easily vectorized.

Answer (score 1):

Type(e) is probably a scalar since e is scalar. Is your right hand side in the assignment EEG.event(e).type a scalar? You will get this error if that is not a scalar.

For example,

```
a(1) = [1 2] % produces an error like yours
a(1) = 1 % Ok
```

Comment: I don't know what RHS means neither what being scalar means. Can you explain?

Comment: I edited answer to expand RHS. scalar means your data has only one element. vector means it has more than one element as a row or column. matrix has both rows and columns.

Comment: Thanks. No in "type" there is only one value. That is why I thought that going into that value would return it

Comment: Can you put a break point in the assignment and check left side and right side independently and see whether their sizes match?

Comment: Not knowing what a scalar, vector or matrix is and continuing to use matlab is going to make your life a living hell. A scalar is a single number, a vector is a list of numbers and a matrix is a table of numbers. You would greatly benefit from a class in linear algebra. Matlab will be much easier after that.

Comment: I know a class would be good, but sadly there is only 24 hours in a day and everything can't be done.

Comment: So Navan, I found a dirty hack way of extracting those values using a function from the toolbox that allows me to extract these values. Thanks for your help. I think until I have a problem like that again where I can really figure out what is going on I'll ask again.